# How to use smart pointers for dynamic arrays?

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

actually I'd need a 2dim container, e. g. `a[m][n]`, for which m and n are determined during runtime.

For 1d arrays I know how to do this using raw pointers, e.g. `double* a = new double[m]` and I would be ready to convert my 2d array to a 1d array `a[j*m + i]` of size m*n.

Often it is recommended to use unique or shared pointers how could I declare such a pointer of size m*n if not a [m][n] pointer? If possible at all...

Comment: why not use vector instead of smart pointer (e.g. std::make_shared / std::make_unique) ? vector is smart too and will release the memory at the end of its scope

Comment: Use a 1d `std::vector` and wrap it up in a class called `matrix` or something like that.

Comment: *it is recommended to use unique or shared pointers* What book does do it?

Comment: Also consider using libs for linear algebra like [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html) instead of making your own (don't reinvent the wheel).

Comment: My question was down-voted. Any hint why so I as a beginner can improve my questions?

Answer (score 1):

> and I would be ready to convert my 2d array to a 1d array a[j*m + i] of size m*n.

It is good that you're ready for it, since that is what you will need to do. The inner dimensions of multidimensional arrays cannot be determined at runtime. Only the outermost dimension can.

> As generally it is recommended to use unique or shared pointers

It is generally recommended to only use shared pointers when you want to have shared ownership. It is better to avoid shared ownership when you don't need it.

For dynamic arrays, `std::vector` is typically a simpler choice than a smart pointer.

Comment: can I fix the size of that vector prior to putting data inside?

Comment: @ManyQuestions You can initialise the vector to have a pre-determined number of elements. The vector will remain the same size if you refrain from adding or removing elements.

Comment: Thanks! One last question on this matter: I actually want directly put data inside the vector. Is this possible? As far as I understand, the vector wants pointers...

Comment: @ManyQuestions I don't understand what "vector wants pointers" means.

Comment: As far as I understand the declaration requires a pointer to indicate the type of data to be stored inside. ege. vector<double*>. For instance I want to put into second position a given integer value of 95, how can I do that?

Comment: @ManyQuestions There is no need to use pointers.

Comment: Thahks @eerorika. I will try that.

Comment: @ManyQuestions "*I actually want directly put data inside the vector. Is this possible?*" - of course it is possible. A `vector` that you can't put data into would be completely useless. "*As far as I understand, the vector wants pointers*" - that is not true. You can declare it to hold value types, eg `vector<double>`, and then store values in it as needed. You can get a `double*` pointer from a `vector<double>` if needed, ie by using the `vector::data()` method.  Or you can use `vector::operator[]` to access individual elements, eg `vector<double> v(InitialSize); v[1] = 95;`